# Mechanism of MSG_WAITALL in Berkeley socket

Tags: sockets

In Berkeley socket, is recv function with MSG_WAITALL flag set, replaces having multiple read functions until the the whole data requested has been read?

I mean does recv function read the whole block determined by the size in one call, whereas the the read function might read part of the data block, and I need to call it multiple times in a loop until the whole block is read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `MSG_WAITALL` tells `recv()` to wait until all of the requested bytes have been read.  However, that it is only supported in blocking mode and not in non-blocking mode, and it only works on stream-oriented sockets, like TCP.  Even then, you also still have to loop, such as on Linux if `recv()` gets interrupted by a signal and has to be called again to continue reading.