# Is there any function like recv_until() in socket for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

I am trying to receive data from a DataTaker DT85 via TCP-IP, but the received data is not everything the DT85 should send.

A delay fixed the problem for me, but I think it is not a good idea to use a delay, because if receiving a message takes longer than the delay, I would have the problem again. Is there any function to fix this issue in a good way?

```
try:
    s.send((messageToSend.encode()))
    debug(f"Sending message: {messageToSend}")
except:
    debug("Sending message failed \n")

sleep(4)

try:
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    debug(f"Received data: {data} \n")
    debug(f"{data.decode('utf-8')} {TERMINATOR}")
except:
    debug("Receiving data failed \n")
    data = ""
```

Comment: You want a recv with a timeout?

Comment: is https://stackoverflow.com/a/22647823/1358308 helpful?  i.e.  `data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE, socket.MSG_WAITALL)` might help

Comment: I think the timeout doesn't work for me, because the server is not sending the data fast enough, so I do not get the whole data, because I received only the beginning of the data until my code continues.

Comment: MSG_WAITALL does not work either, because I don't want to receive a specific amount of data. I just want to receive all data the server sends.